# How to save images and retrieve them using glide in android

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-glide

I am using Glide to show images in recyclerview from urls. I have followed a couple of examples but still cant show the images offline too(when app is closed and reopened with no internet connectivity).

Any solution?

I have used the below code inside the adapter for recyclerView:

```
 Glide.with(mContext)
            .load(imgUrl)
            .asBitmap()
            .into(new SimpleTarget<Bitmap>() {
                @Override
                public void onResourceReady(Bitmap resource, GlideAnimation<? super Bitmap> glideAnimation) {
                    holder.thumbnail.setImageBitmap(resource);
                }
            });
```

Comment: You can use placeholder, when offline. checkout this https://inthecheesefactory.com/blog/get-to-know-glide-recommended-by-google/en

Answer (score 0):

try this use `.diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)` to  download and cache the images

```
Glide.with(this)
 .load(url)
 .placeholder(R.drawable.placeholder_image) 
 .error(R.drawable.error_image)
 .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE)
 .into(imageView);
```

Comment: Nope.. it shows images online.. when i close the app,go offline and reopen the app recyclerview is empty.

Comment: i thin than you have to use place holder check updated ans

Comment: placeholder is going to just put the defined image not the cached image.

Comment: did you try with .diskCacheStrategy(DiskCacheStrategy.SOURCE) this

Comment: yes , i have used a default icon eg-ic_launcher for placeholder.. I think if it was possible to give the cached images over here than it would be done